# Pandas total row, but some cells aren't totals

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I am trying to generate a total row for my dataframe, but some of the columns in the total row are proportions of the total rather than a sum. example below:

```
       | Column A | Column B | Column Proportion |
       | -------- | -------- |-------------------|
       | 100      | 200      |        2%         |
       | 3        | 5        |        1.67%      |
```

**total      103      | 205      |        1.99%      |**

column proportion is calculated by: column B / column A
The total is a sum for columns a and b, but not a sum for the proportion column.

Thank you.

I tried using the .sum function.

Comment: add your dataframe to the question by showing the output `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a total row for your DataFrame by using the sum() function for columns A and B and then calculate the proportion in the total row based on these sums.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Column A': [100, 3],
    'Column B': [200, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sum_a = df['Column A'].sum()
sum_b = df['Column B'].sum()
total_row = {
    'Column A': sum_a,
    'Column B': sum_b,
    'Column Proportion': sum_b / sum_a * 100  # Calculate proportion
}
df = df.append(total_row, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```